# How get li number using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How get '`li`' number from drag and drop `li`

example,

```
<ol>
    1. <li>A</li>
    2. <li>B</li>
    3. <li>C</li>
    4. <li>D</li>
    5. <li>E</li>
</ol>
```

the number is just example the fixed li number, and if i drag and drop the li and i get the fixed li number if, like this

```
<ol>
    1. <li>E</li>
    2. <li>C</li>
    3. <li>B</li>
    4. <li>D</li>
    5. <li>A</li>
</ol>
```

The result is :

```
E is||= 1
C is||= 2
B is||= 3
D is||= 4
A is||= 5
```

i try to use this code, but still get '-1'

```
var index = $(this).parent('ol').index();
```

i get li number from this event

```
onDrop: function ($item, container, _super, event) {
      item.removeClass(container.group.options.draggedClass).removeAttr("style")
      $("body").removeClass(container.group.options.bodyClass)
      var index = $(this).parent('ol').index();
      $( ".number" ).text( "That was div index #" + index );
},
```

thanks

Comment: how are you getting the number of li on what event?

Comment: @guradio, thanks for the question, i answer in my question

Comment: `$('li').on('click', function() {
  console.log(this.textContent + ' - Index - ' + $(this).index());
});`

Comment: `var index = $(this).index();` remove the `.parent('ol')` and add `+1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Example (getting update `li` original and changed index):-

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) { 
            console.log('update: '+(ui.item.index()+1))
        },
        start: function(event, ui) { 
            console.log('start: ' +(ui.item.index()+1))
        }
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
ol li {
  background-color:green;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:10px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ol id="sortable">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want the numbers to be associated even after dragging.  Here's a way of doing it.

```js
$( "#sortable" )
  .sortable()
  .find("li")
    .each(function (index) {
      $(this).prepend(index+1 + ". ");
    })
```

```css
ol li {
  background-color:#777;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:2px;
  color:black;
}

ol {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ol id="sortable">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @thanks the number is fixed 1,2,3,4,5 and a,b,c,d,e is dinamic name if i drag 5. E to 1. A  the result E is 1 and A is 5